# Convert string to object for .SetChoices() Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I have a string `'{ name:"All", value:"All"},{ name:"Home", value:"Home" },{ name:"Coding", value:"Coding" }'` but I want to put it in the `.SetChoices()` for my Discord bot's command. The reason I need this, is because when I edit an external JSON file, it automatically adds values to the Choices for this command. And it also is needed for the command's functionality.

But I need some sort of object to go inside the `.SetChoices()`. And when I have an array of objects, it doesn't like it and gives an error. I wanted to see if there was a way to convert this string into multiple objects that would be in one variable so I don't have to add new values to both the external JSON and also another object.

Kinda what I want is for one variable to be equal to `{ name:"All", value:"All" },{ name:"Home", value:"Home" },{ name:"Coding", value:"Coding" }` (multiple objects). But I don't know if it is possible.

Comment: can u show me, what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your objects to be passed into method not as array of objects but as objects themselves, you can use [array destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Just as an example, here how you can use the destruction to pass the arguments and how it will work:

```js
// You store your choices as array of objects and parse them
// into array which will look like this one:
const choices = [
  {name: "All", value: "All"},
  {name: "Home", value: "Home"},
  {name: "Coding", value: "Coding"}
];

// Now you just need to add `...` to the beginning of the array
// in order to destruct it:
setChoices(...choices);

// Code above is equivalent of you calling the method with objects
// passed as arguments:
setChoices(choices[0], choices[1], choices[2]);
setChoices(
  {name: "All", value: "All"}, 
  {name: "Home", value: "Home"},
  {name: "Coding", value: "Coding"}
);
```

All you need is just store the array of choices in JSON, parse it into the array and destruct the following array when passing into `setChoices` method.

Comment: that's not dynamic like I want. Because I'll still need to add choices[3], choices[4], etc. after I edit the JSON file.

Comment: @BowersIndustry Last two calls are just an example. If you have 4 items in your array, then 4 attributes will be passed to the methods as arguments, if 5 items — then 5 arguments and so on. Just read more about how it works and try it out yourself in terminal.